# jQuery: Get Linenumber of jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, plugins, seo

Im working on an SEO-Analalyzing plugin for jQuery. My plugin lists all related  tips/errors on the top of the page. Now instead of listing only the tips, i want to show on which line the user can find the related object too.
My Querstion:
Is it possible to get the linenumber of a jQuery object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically load code and get line number of parse error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643552/dynamically-load-code-and-get-line-number-of-parse-error)

Comment: not exact dupe... but they are looking for the same outcome, which is to obtain the line number of the specific piece of code.